# Strip html tags in php for user view before emailing

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a php project which involves jquery and ajax. The data gets processed through ajax call and the message gets displayed in an email dialog box.
I want the email to be html enabled but the thing is that html tags should be invisible for display before hitting send button. Looking for some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question isn't clear!

Comment: There are many ways to strip tags in php and Regex. Google this title you will find many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Are you displaying the response of the ajax call in a textarea?  If so, then you can't get rid of the html tags because you will lose all the formatting.

If the content needs to be editable then perhaps try an embedded WYSIWYG editor such as TinyMCE.

If the content doesn't need to be editable then simply insert the html into a div instead of a textarea. See https://api.jquery.com/html/

If you simply want to strip tags then the strip_tags() PHP function will do that for you.

Comment: ya but am using the same data for sending email. if i use strip tags then i am getting a plain text email body.

Comment: Is the email body supposed to be editable by the user? Are you displaying it in a textarea?

Comment: yes am displaying in a text area..the user should only see the message text. No the user wont be able to edit it

Comment: Then don't use a textarea. Insert the content into a div. Use this: https://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

You can display the content using javascripts `innerHTML`. It will show the content as marked up by the html, not the html tags and plain text.

Have you tried any code yet? It is not clear what you are trying to do, perhaps you wish for the user to be able to edit the email, if so you would need to use a script that supported your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You say the you are displaying the response which you get from the php server. This approach is not so tidy but if you want this might be a simple solution. Use php `strip_tags()` and create a different response and add it to your response string with an identifiable key. The you have two response values which one can be used to show to the user and the other can be emailed which contains the original html included response.

you can display the response without the html tags to the user.